# Converting dataframe fraction to float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to convert the string values in column b to float. Wondering how should I make it.

```
A    B
1    16-1/4
2    3-1/4
3    21-1/4
4    8-1/4
```

Comment: what is the expected output of `B` ?

Comment: 16.25 etc.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

Give `map` a try to avoid limit 100 rows on `pd.eval`

```
df['C'] = df.B.str.replace('-', '+').map(pd.eval)
```

---

**Original**:

As your comment, it seems you adding the fraction to the whole number, so the solution would be

```
df['C'] = pd.eval(df.B.str.replace('-', '+'))

Out[5]:
   A       B      C
0  1  16-1/4  16.25
1  2   3-1/4   3.25
2  3  21-1/4  21.25
3  4   8-1/4   8.25
```

Comment: Unfortunately.....I have more than 100 rows which causes the error: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

Comment: @JAY.Y: try use `map` with `pd.eval` as my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in Python function `eval()`:

```
df.B = df.B.apply(eval)
```

---

Test:

```
In[1]: df
```

> ```
>    A       B
> 0  1  16-1/4
> 1  2   3-1/4
> 2  3  21-1/4
> 3  4   8-1/4
> ```

```
In[2]: df.B = df.B.apply(eval)
In[3]: df
```

> ```
>    A      B
> 0  1  15.75
> 1  2   2.75
> 2  3  20.75
> 3  4   7.75
> ```